# Kendo Dropdown with Knockout get full object of selected

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui

I have a kendo dropdownlist mixed with knockout

```
<div><input data-bind="kendoDropDownList: TransactionCards" /></div>

var TransactionCards = {
    data:fi,
    dataTextField: 'Card.Number',
    dataValueField: 'Card.FundingId',
    value: transactionId
};
```

How can I get the full object within transactionId? Right now i receive the fundingId which i understand, but I have a new piece which requires knowing more about the selected item. How can I get the full object as the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that the current KendoDropDownList does not support having a complex object as a data value. This post has a proper link to a way to solve the problem by using an additional ko.computed.

[Set the binding of a dropdown in knockout to an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613550/set-the-binding-of-a-dropdown-in-knockout-to-an-object/15639369#15639369)

Answer (score 0):

if you don't specify dataValueField the select object will be assigned to the value object